# Putting a shortcut on the desktop of all the people in a particular OU?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, files, folder-redirection, organizational-unit

At work we have all the user desktops redirected to a server.

Within a all the users in an OU I need to put the same shortcut on all of their desktops.  Is there an easier way to do this than just copy them out to each and every profile, or write a script to copy them out to each and every profile?  Or is that the standard way of doing so when a particular file or shortcut should be on all of their desktops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Group Policy Preferences shortcut settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753580.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 1):

GPP is generally the preferred way to do this (as pointed out by @MDMArra ), though depending on the OS of your client machines, you may wish to create a logon script for the users in question that creates (or copies) the shortcut for them, as GPPs occasionally create difficult-to-troubleshoot problems with XP clients.

Comment: That's a good point...we have both...

Comment: Many of the quirks with GPP on XP can be solved by adding a logon script with `echo n|gpupdate /target:user /force` on the GPO with the Group Policy Prefs. Hacky, but it's saved me lately.